# How to read a text file 3 characters at a time?

Tags: c, ascii, fgetc

I'm learning to program in C, and right now my homework is like this. I am supposed to be able to take a text file with words/letters and my program should print the ascii codes+1 of the letters it gets. It's "encoding" it. So for example the letter "A" would be printed as 066. So my problem is the program needs to also be able to decode those ascii codes back to letters, but I don't know how to get my program to read 3 numbers at once. I used

```
c = fgetc(pF);  
while (c != EOF) {  
fprintf(pF2,"%03i",c+1); 
c = fgetc(pF);
```

to read the file one character at a time. Should I use something similar to get the 3 numbers I need, or would it be something completely different?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int encode(){
char * fName = "testR.txt";
char * fName2="testW.txt";
FILE * pF;
FILE * pF2;
char c, cArray[500];
int i=0;

pF = fopen(fName, "r");
if ( pF == NULL ) {
    printf("Error: The specified file could not be opened.\n");
    return -1;
}
pF2 = fopen(fName2, "w");

c = fgetc(pF);
while (c != EOF) {
fprintf(pF2,"%03i",c+1);
    c = fgetc(pF);
}
fclose(pF); 
fclose(pF2);
return;
}

char decode(){
char * fName = "testW.txt";
char * fName2="testW2.txt";
char * buf;
FILE * pF;
FILE * pF2;
char  cArray[500];
char buffer[4];
     buffer[3] = '\0';

pF = fopen(fName, "r");
if ( pF == NULL ) {
    printf("Error: The specified file could not be opened.\n");
    return -1;
}
pF2 = fopen(fName2, "w");
while (fread(buffer, 3, 1, stdin)){
putchar((atoi(buffer)-1) & 0xFF);
}
fclose(pF); 
fclose(pF2);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
char c;

if ( argc != 2 ) { 
  printf("Incorrect number of arguments.\n"); 
  exit(-1); 
} 

if (strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0){
   encode();
   }
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0){
   decode();
   }
return 0;
}
```

I am aware that my code is a mess and there are probably things that shouldn't be there from all the changes I've been trying to make =[

Comment: fread(buf, 1, 3, pF);

Comment: would I still use (c != EOF)?

Comment: no. Declare buf first then use fread. thes reads 3 chars from pF and stores it in buf.

Comment: The function returns the number of elements read with respect to the 3rd argument, count. Normally an error when the return value and count don't match.

Comment: Alright, I think I have that, but how do I make it loop to read the whole file?

Comment: What encoding is the text file? If it's plain ASCII, you read one byte, and the only issue is formatting. If it's other than ASCII, you need to do something different. "Read words/letters from a text file" is meaningless if we (and you) don't know anything about the encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Encoding:

```
int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    printf("%.3d", (c+1)&0xFF);
```

Decoding:

```
char buffer[4];
buffer[3] = '\0';

while (fread(buffer, 3, 1, stdin))
    putchar((atoi(buffer)-1) & 0xFF);
```

Technically, if the output does not end with a newline when encoding, the output is not a text file. There's no error checking on the input.  The `fread()` will return 1 when it reads a triplet of characters; otherwise, it will return 0.

### Working Programs

#### e3.c — encryption

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("%.3d", (c+1)&0xFF);
    return 0;
}
```

#### d3.c — decryption

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[4];
    buffer[3] = '\0';

    while (fread(buffer, 3, 1, stdin))
        putchar((atoi(buffer)-1) & 0xFF);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample output

```
$ e3 < e3.c
036106111100109118101102033061116117101106112047105063011011106111117033110098106111041119112106101042011124011033033033033106111117033100060011011033033033033120105106109102033041041100033062033104102117100105098115041042042033034062033070080071042011033033033033033033033033113115106111117103041035038047052101035045033041100044050042039049121071071042060011033033033033115102117118115111033049060011126011011$
$
```

The dollar at the end of the line is the prompt.

```
$ e3 <e3.c | d3
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("%.3d", (c+1)&0xFF);
    return 0;
}

$ e3 <e3.c | d3 | diff e3.c -
$
```

Basic round-tripping the encoding and decoding shows that the code works.

Comment: Right, that's the first part of the program. It already does that. Now I'm trying to make another function within my program that changes '066' back into "A", and then writing "A" into a new document, the looping this until basically I get the original document.

Comment: That's the 'encoding' part; given `A`, it will output `066`.  The decoding reads three characters into a null-terminated buffer, then applies `atoi()` to get 66, subtracts 1, to get back 65, which it outputs as a character.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Exactly. That second part is giving me trouble.

Comment: +1. I stand corrected. Glad I didn't DV. :-) Deleting my comment to remove the clutter.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (fread(buf, 1, 3, pF) == 3) 
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is totally wrong if the file is plain ASCII text; reading a single character requires reading one byte, not three.

Comment: Got it, I feel silly. So the program now makes the file I'm trying to make, but there's nothing in it and the program doesn't really terminate properly. Are the three characters being read stored in buf, or if not is there somewhere I can get to them? Because I need to convert them from ascii codes back into characters.

Comment: The three characters read from the file are stored in `buf`, which must be defined as an array of char (e.g. `char buf[3]`). So in your example, if your input file had the characters `066`, then after fread has been called `buf[0]` will contain the character `0`, `buf[1]` will contain the character `6` and `buf[2]` will contain the character `6`.

Comment: @KenWhite, it's my understanding the op is encoding the character value as a 3 digit string into the file; i.e., "%03i". This would of course require a read of 3 characters. Line termination doesn't seem to be an issue, so binary/text is so far irrelevant.

Comment: Assuming this was compliant with whatever encoding the OP's input file is, the only major issue is the order of the size/count parameters to `fread`. If it is indeed as described, the "item" being read is *exactly* three chars, and as such a partial-read is a failure condition. Therefore, this should read `while (fread(buf, 3, 1, pF) == 1)`. All of that assuming it is the format the OP wants (which I'm honestly doubting, as it doesn't account for whitespace, line separators, etc. without knowing the file format its impossible to answer accurately).

Comment: @bvj: Where do you get that from "take a text file with words/letters and my program should print the ascii codes+1 of the letters it gets"? It talks about "encoding" the output, not "reading from an encoded file", and it talks about reading 'the letter "A"', not the three characters '065'. "A text file with word and letters" can be created with `copy con` from a command prompt.

Comment: The file format I believe is plaintext(it's a .txt file), and there are no whitespaces or line separators in the file I'm drawing from.

Comment: @WhozCraig the write is a sequential stream of sizeof(char) elements, not 3-byte chunks of data. Your point is certainly relevant when writing binary data via fwrite given endianness concerns.

Comment: Apparently I wasn't clear enough, sorry if I'm wasting your guys's time. The program has 2 command line switches. The first one is -e which will take a plaintext document and create a new document changing each character into a number. The second switch is -d which should take the 3 NUMBERS and change them back into letters.

Comment: @user2985744 you still didn't clarify the gambit here. Are the "3 NUMBERS" actually *character digits* ?? if so, most of this is relevant (and I believe they are).

Comment: @bvj endianess concerns has nothing to do with my comment. my comment surrounds the consumption of data from the stream. `fread(buf,1,3,pF)` can consume "up-to-three-chars" from the input stream with success, and the failure condition ( == 3) is logical, but the under-read data is lost (i.e. if there were only 2 chars they're now in `buf` but you don't know that because all you know is 3 weren't read). Using `fread(buf,3,1,pF)` ensures you either get them *all* or none, and no under-read is lost. that was my only point.

Comment: @bvj: The OP has reversed the question three times now (first unclear, then in a comment to your post "plain text", and then in a comment to Jonathan's answer it's different based on a command-line switch and the code does both and now that's relevant because it is indeed not a plain text file and actually needs to be reverted to the plain text file it was before).

Comment: @KenWhite Initially, I posted the first comment, but expanded the comment into an Answer given the op's curiosity about reading the entire source file. I didn't intend to invite so much attention :)